# Company is worried about exposing our PII to Tableau, Can we run Tableau without exposing our data to any 3rd parties?

Tags: security

I'm looking to understand a bit more from the technical side about how Tableau (The company itself) works with the data that everyone is providing them.

My company is looking to use Tableau as our main visualization tool as we grow larger, but we have a lot PII data, and just confidential data in general that we are not able to expose for compliance reasons to any 3rd parties.

Is there a way to run Tableau, and take advantage of all of the features that it has (Or a majority subset) in a way where we can still make connections to our reporting databases (MySQL/Postgres/RedShift), and also in such a way that a team of Data scientists can all access this information together, but silo it so that none of this information ever touches the Tableau company servers?

I know that most likely in good faith they do not store this information, but that is not enough for compliance reasons for us to work off of.

If I had an inherent mis understanding of the way in which Tableau operates I apologize, would love to learn more!

Thanks for the help

Comment: You can get an on premises Tableau server. It has a different pricing structure than the web app.

Comment: Best idea I can have: contact a Tableau's sales representative to see how they can (or can not) match your compliance requirements and at which cost.

Answer (score 1):

There are several alternatives:

- since you are `looking to use Tableau as our main visualization tool`, you might try other on-premise alternatives, such as:

  - [Pentaho Community Edition](https://community.hitachivantara.com/s/pentaho)
  - [QlikView on-premise](https://www.qlik.com/us/products/qlikview/customer-resources)
- Also, there is [on-premise](https://www.tableau.com/pricing/teams-orgs#server) license for Tableau